# htaccess redirect full url (including query string)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently I use this code for rewriting my urls:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

The url `http://www.website.com/test/` gets redirected to `index.php?url=test/`. I also would like that `http://www.website.com/test.php?page=123` gets redirected to `index.php?url=test.php%3Fpage%3D123` so I can use this for dynamically detecting old redirects. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Use %{QUERY_STRING}

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1%{QUERY_STRING}
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1?%{QUERY_STRING}` works for `test.php?page=123` but not for `test.php?page=123&test=123`; the & needs to be replaced by %3F

Comment: You can use a B flag, which is not %3F, but simillar
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b